# Setting a Firebase Observable List as an object/variable in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular2-services

```
@Injectable()

export class ArticlesService {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  private _url = 'http://59176d8f5b63ed0011251710.mockapi.io/api/v1/articles';

  constructor(private _http: Http, db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('/');
  }

  getAllArticles(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }

  getAnArticle(articleId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(`${this._url}/${articleId}`)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
}
```

The .json objects located in both, the `items` object and the `_url` variable are similar.  However I need to replace the `private _url` variable with the content retrieved from the Firebase object.  I'm sure the answer is right in front of me, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to consume data from your firebase db instead of the mock API. If that's what your looking for read next.

Update your **`ArticlesService`** constructor

```
constructor(
   private db: AngularFireDatabase
){}
```

Change your **`getAllArticles()`** to this

```
getAllArticles(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
   return this.db.list('/');
}
```

in your component

```
constructor(
   private as: ArticlesService
){}

ngOnInit() { 
    this.as.getAllEvents()
      .subscribe(data => this.items = data);
}
```

Later iterate `items` with a `*ngFor` in your template. (you don't have to use the `async` pipe in this method)

**For `getAnArticle()`**

Every item will have a `$key` which will have the unique id of the item (it will be a random string set by firebase when creating). In your case you can use your the `id` (`articleId`) instead of `$key`.

Change your **`getAnArticle()`** to this

```
getAnArticle(articleId: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
    return this.db.object('/' + articleId);
}
```